# htaccess url mod_rewrite caching and butification

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sorry if it's a duplicate one,but i didn't come across questions that meet my queries.To simply put it,I've divided my question in three parts.ie.

1. Caching related
2. Url beautification
3. Tutorials.

So..
**1.**Dynamically convert**

```
  myfile_min_vXX.js --> myfile.js
  myfile_min_vXX.css --> myfile.css
```

via mod_rewrite.These file maybe in sub folder like images|scrpt|js etc.So i've to do it from root directory .htaccess file.

**2.**Beautification of url.**
Consider-

```
mydomain/name1_val1/name2_val2/../namenN_valN ---> mydomain/file.php?name1=val1&name2=val2 ..
```

making regular expression conversion for this in .htaccess is out of my level.

**3.**
I need a `good tutorial on mod_rewrite of Apache likely "Complete reference" type`.

Thanks for your kind appreciation.

Comment: These really should be 3 separate questions, IMO.

Comment: Maybe yes,but it's all about mod_rewrite. :)

Answer (score 1):

For number 1:

```
RewriteRule ^myfile_min_vXX.js$    script/myfile.js
RewriteRule ^myfile_min_vXX.css$   style/myfile.css
```

Number 2:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) file.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
```

Number 3:
best mod_rewrite tutorial I've seen is apache documentation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

For examples of using this mod check apache wiki:
http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite

Remember apache is using prel compatible regular expresion:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll start you off with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html then. I don't claim to be a mod_rewrite expect, so I won't try on the rest. :)